# How do I let a variable be equal to the regex function of a string

Tags: javascript, regex

to clarify I'm using React and Material UI. I have strings in the format of : `CAD - Canadian Dollar` and I would like to use regex to create a string that would be equivalent to `Canadian Dollar`. Essentially the everything before the `-` would need to removed, and the one blank space in front of it would need to be removed as well. Following that I would like to set some variable to be equal to that returning string.

Here is my attempt:

```
const userCurrency = 'USD - United States Dollar'

const varSetter = (e) => {
        var test1 = e.target.innerText;
        setUserCurrency(test1);
        console.log(userCurrency);

        const currencyRegex = userCurrency.match(/[^-]*$/g)


        console.log(currencyRegex);
      }
```

This returns an array `[' United States Dollar', '']`  but how do I remove the leading whitespace, and have the result as a string and not an array? Thank you!

Comment: `userCurrency.split(" - ").slice(1).join(" - ")` - removes everything up to and including the *first* `" - "` - though, there's probably no reason to think that any currency has `" - "` in its name, but you never know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few ways you could handle this... if all of the strings have the same pattern of `[prefix] - [currency name]` then you could change your RegEx to use a [lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), and combine this with [array destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment):

```js
const [currency] = 'USD - United States Dollar'.match(/(?<=-\s).+/)

console.log(currency);  // 'United States Dollar'
```

However, do you really need a regular expression? If it's always a three character prefix, then `substring` is fit for purpose:

```js
const currency = 'USD - United States Dollar'.substring(6);

console.log(currency);  // 'United States Dollar'
```

Comment: It's always the same pattern, I guess substring is the way

Answer (score 1):

Use the `replace()` function to remove the match of the pattern.

```
const currencyRegex = userCurrency.replace(/.*\s+-\s+/, '');
```

This regexp matches everything up to the last `-`. It also requires whitespace around the `-`, and removes the whitespace after it as well.

Comment: This will fail for "GWP - Guinea-Bissau Peso" - it will result in "Bissau Peso"

Comment: Good point, I've added required whitespace around the `-`.